# Update products stock once creating order programmatically in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, orders

I write a plugin to quickly buy a product not through button `Add to cart`.

I create a custom attribute is `Color`, each color has the number of products.

Problem is: when I click button quickly buy a product.

It will auto-insert an order in WooCommerce > Order.

But in Stock, don't reduce the number of product I bought.

My code to process like:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_sb_test_ajax", "sb_test_ajax_callback");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_sb_test_ajax", "sb_test_ajax_callback");

function sb_test_ajax_callback(){
    $address = array(
            'phone'      => $_POST['phone'],
        );

    $order = wc_create_order(array('customer_id'=>get_current_user_id()));
    // print_r($order);
    update_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_phone', $_POST['phone']);
    update_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_email', $_POST['email']);
    update_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_address_1', 'Tại: '.$_POST['dia_chi']);
    update_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_last_name', 'Tên: '.$_POST['ho_ten']);
    $order->set_customer_user_agent( wc_get_user_agent() );
    $order->set_customer_note($_POST['ghi_chu']);
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );

    if( isset($_POST['product_id']) && $_POST['product_id'] ){
        $id = ($_POST['variation_id']) ? $_POST['variation_id'] : $_POST['product_id'];
        $order->add_product( get_product( $id ), $_POST['qty'] ); //(get_product with id and next is for quantity)
        $order->calculate_totals();

    } else {
        $cart = WC()->cart;
        //print_r($cart);
        $cart_hash = md5( json_encode( wc_clean( $cart->get_cart_for_session() ) ) . $cart->total );
        $order->set_cart_hash( $cart_hash );
        WC_Checkout::create_order_line_items( $order, $cart );
        $order->set_total( $cart->total );

        $order->set_shipping_total( $cart->shipping_total );
        $order->set_discount_total( $cart->get_cart_discount_total() );
        $order->set_discount_tax( $cart->get_cart_discount_tax_total() );
        $order->set_cart_tax( $cart->tax_total );
        $order->set_shipping_tax( $cart->shipping_tax_total );
        WC_Checkout::create_order_fee_lines( $order, $cart );
        WC_Checkout::create_order_shipping_lines( $order, WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ), WC()->shipping->get_packages() );
        WC_Checkout::create_order_tax_lines( $order, $cart );
        WC_Checkout::create_order_coupon_lines( $order, $cart );
        $cart->empty_cart();
    }

    $order->save();

    WC()->payment_gateways();
    WC()->shipping();

    // Load mailer.
    $mailer = WC()->mailer();
    $email_to_send = 'new_order';
    $mails = $mailer->get_emails();

    if ( ! empty( $mails ) ) {
        foreach ( $mails as $mail ) {
            if ( $mail->id == $email_to_send ) {
                $mail->trigger( $order->get_id(), $order );
                /* translators: %s: email title */
                $order->add_order_note( sprintf( __( '%s don't have any notes.', 'woocommerce' ), $mail->title ), false, true );
            }
        }
    }
}

// add custom button woo
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','cmk_additional_button');
function cmk_additional_button() {
?>
<br/>
<a href="#modal" class="mua_nhanh_nhanh">Quick Buy</a>
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <div class="mua_nhanh">
        <h3>Buy a product: <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <form action="" method="post" id="buy_click_form">
        <input type="hidden" value="buy_click" name="action">
        <input id="id_sp" type="hidden" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" name="product_id">
        <input id="ho_ten" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
        <input id="email_kk" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <input id="dia_chi" type="text" placeholder="Address"/>
        <input type="tel" value="" name="phone" class="one_click_tel" placeholder="Phone number:" onFocus="if(this.value=='') this.value='+84';" >
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity'/>
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='1' class='qty' onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
    <textarea rows="2" id="ghi_chu" placeholder="Note(optinal)"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="buy_click" >Buy Now</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to reduce the number of product in Stock after buying successful a product?

I created variable product look like:

[image]

You can see I have 3 variable products. Each product has different price and amount of number in stock.

This is front-end page, I can choose any variable product to buy (in this case, I choose the product to have red color). And click button Quick Buy.

[image]

> **Problem is:** it only reduce stock in parent product while I choose a variation of this product. Should reduce the stock of product variation instead of parent variable product.

I check again, it still is 10 product. Don't have any stock in variable product reduce.

[image]

Comment: Which WC version you're using and why didn't you validate and sanitize data? Even you didn't use any nonce!

Check this file there are some stock related functions https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-stock-functions.php

Comment: hi @obiPlabon. I using WC 3.3.1. I don't have experience with Wordpress. So, I just tried to find why the stock is not updated when I buy a product is successful. I found function `$order->reduce_order_stock();` but seem it is not working.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I compress a plugin at here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10zAY_egSeAxVRkZhENI6x6Z7FuBRC5RW.

Comment: Can you install this plugin?

Comment: @vanloc I got it. I have found the missing little thing for everything needed. I have  removed a lot of errors. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **Update** - The right **`WC_Order`** method **to update STOCK** is [**`payment_complete()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#90-139).
>
> This method also send **email notification**s and add 2 admin notes (one for stock update and the other for status change)

Now in your code there is a lot of little errors and outdated code. you will have to use CRUD setters method everywhere you can. I have make changes and revisited your main function code:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_sb_test_ajax", "sb_test_ajax_callback");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_sb_test_ajax", "sb_test_ajax_callback");

function sb_test_ajax_callback(){
    $order = wc_create_order(array('customer_id'=>get_current_user_id()));
    $order->set_customer_user_agent( wc_get_user_agent() );
    $order->set_customer_ip_address( WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address() );
    $order->set_currency( get_woocommerce_currency() );
    $order->set_prices_include_tax( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_prices_include_tax' ) );
    
    // Customer data (use CRUD setters)
    $order->set_billing_phone( $_POST['phone'] );
    $order->set_billing_email( $_POST['email'] );
    $order->set_shipping_address_1( 'Tại: '.$_POST['dia_chi'] );
    $order->set_shipping_last_name( 'Tên: '.$_POST['ho_ten'] );
    $order->set_customer_note( $_POST['ghi_chu'] );

    if( isset($_POST['product_id']) && $_POST['product_id'] ){
        $product_id = ($_POST['variation_id']) ? $_POST['variation_id'] : $_POST['product_id'];
        // Get_product with id and next is for quantity
        $order->add_product( wc_get_product( $product_id ), $_POST['quantity'] ); // <= corrected
    } else {
        $cart = WC()->cart;
        $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
        $shipping_packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
        $cart_hash = md5( json_encode( wc_clean( $cart->get_cart_for_session() ) ) . $cart->total );
        $order->set_cart_hash( $cart_hash );
        $order->set_total( $cart->total );
        $order->set_shipping_total( $cart->shipping_total );
        $order->set_discount_total( $cart->get_cart_discount_total() );
        $order->set_discount_tax( $cart->get_cart_discount_tax_total() );
        $order->set_cart_tax( $cart->tax_total );
        $order->set_shipping_tax( $cart->shipping_tax_total );
        WC()->checkout->create_order_line_items( $order, $cart );
        WC()->checkout->create_order_shipping_lines( $order, $chosen_shipping_methods, $shipping_packages );
        WC()->checkout->create_order_tax_lines( $order, $cart );
        WC()->checkout->create_order_coupon_lines( $order, $cart );
        WC()->checkout->create_order_fee_lines( $order, $cart );
        $cart->empty_cart();
    }
    
    // [Not really needed] Get an instance of  WC_emails object
    # $mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();
    # $email_title = $mailer['WC_Email_New_Order']->title; // email title
    
    // [Not really needed] Admin note
    # $note = sprintf( __( "%s don't have any notes.", "woocommerce" ), $email_title );
    # $order->add_order_note( $note, false, true );
    
    // Update totals
    $order->calculate_totals();

    // Save the data
    $order->save();

    ## STOCK and Status update
    $order->payment_complete();

    ## [NOT needed] Send new order email notification
    # $mailer['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order->get_id() );
    # echo '<p>Order generated</p>';
}
```

Tested and works *(on WooCommerce version 3.2.6)*.

> Simple products or product variations get their stock updated.

[image]

Comment: Hi @loic theaztec, I was using `wc_reduce_stock_levels($order->get_id());`. But it only reduces in parent product. In my case, I have 3 custom product (include 3 colors), each color has a price. Should reduce the stock of a variable product instead of parent product.

Comment: You can see my updated question. I added an image to easy know. Wait 3 minutes to update.

Comment: Yes, like your comment. I think the stock of parent product is total of number stock in product variations. If the customer buys a variation product, the stock of this variation product and parent product should be reduced both. You can see my updated question. I tried to change Woo to English language but my WC depends on WP language. So, have some difficulty when reading in my image. Hope you help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will back to WC 3.2.6 if this necessary. I think this problem appear many times if anyone creates a custom button to quick buy product don't need `Cart` in WC.

Comment: @, I updated my code like your answer. It's not working in my case. It only reduces parent variable product. I debug and found out the problem is: always apply for the id of parent product. It doesn't update id of the variable product. Because in `WC->Order`, Order of customer always is: parent variable product. Isn't variable product with color.

Comment: @vanloc I don't have this problem… The correct stock is dicreased on the product variation too. For me it works. That means that something is wrong in your installation with WC 3.3.1 (or it could be the theme, a plugin)...